# Convert String to a Linked List

Tags: c, list, pointers, linked-list, malloc

1) I need to read in a string from a file and convert that string to a linked list

So...If i read in this string "Some String"

The linked list will look like this

node1  - "S"

node2  - "o"

node3  - "m"

node4  - "e"

node5  - NULL

node6  - "S"

node7  - "t"

node8  - "r"

node9  - "i"

node10 - "n"

node11 - "g"

node12 - NULL

NULL would be issued for " " (spaces) and for "\0" null character

Whats the best way to implement this..

```
typedef struct node
{
// each node holds a single character
char data;

// pointer to next node in linked list
struct node *next;
} node;

int i;
char buffer[1032];

    FILE *ifp = fopen("file.txt", "rb");

    //read the first line of file
    fscanf(ifp, "%s", buffer);

node *myList = malloc(sizeof(node));

for(i = 0; i < strlen(buffer); i++)
    /*I DON'T KNOW WHAT TO DO HERE!!!!*/
```

Here I'm lost, Or if I'm completely wrong with my implementation please let me know

Comment: Please remember to tag your questions with the language you're using (this could be C or C++).

Comment: `/*I DON'T KNOW WHAT TO DO HERE!!!!*/`? Well, I'd say that for each character in the string, you need to create and initialize a node, and then point the tail of the list at the new node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `fscanf(ifp, "%s", buffer);` will stop after it read "Some".I use fgets() instead. And in the manual(man fgets):

> fgets()  reads  in at most one less than size characters from stream
>   and  stores  them  into  the  buffer pointed  to  by  s.   Reading
>   stops after an EOF or a newline.  If a newline is read, it is stored
>   into the buffer.  A '\0' is stored after the last character in the
>   buffer.

the last '\0' make it convenient to handle the buffer as a string.
so my code after `FILE *ifp = fopen("file.txt", "rb");` is:

```
fgets(buffer,1032-1,ifp);
node *myList,*head,*pre = NULL;

for(i = 0; buffer[i] != '\0' ; i++) {
    myList = malloc(sizeof(node));
    myList->data = buffer[i];   
    if(pre!=NULL)
        pre->next = myList;
    else
        head = myList;
    pre = myList;
}

while(head!=NULL) {
    printf("%c\n",head->data);
    head=head->next;
}
fclose(ifp);
```

your implement stores '\n' and space as NULL,its OK when you change

```
myList->data = buffer[i];
```

to

```
if(buffer[i]=='\n' || buffer[i]==' ')
    myList->data = 0;
else
    myList->data = buffer[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct node {
    char data;         // each node holds a single character
    struct node *next; // pointer to next node in linked list
} node;

int
main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int i;
    FILE* fp = fopen("example.txt", "r");   
    if (!fp) {
        perror("fopen");
        exit(1);
    }

    node *top = NULL;
    node *cur = NULL;
    int c;
    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) >= 0) {
        node *item = malloc(sizeof(node));
        item->data = c;
        item->next = NULL;
        if (!cur) {
            // first time, store top.
            top = cur = item;
        } else {
            // chain nexts.
            cur->next = item;
            cur = item;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);

    // print datas
    cur = top;
    while (cur) {
        printf("%c\n", cur->data);
        cur = cur->next;
    }

    // free datas
    cur = top;
    while (cur) {
        node *item = cur->next;
        free(cur);
        cur = item;
    }
    return 0;
}
```